# When matching two column values conditionally, why are several <NA> values printed in the resulting data frame that is printed to the RStudio console?

Tags: r, filter

When I check to see if one column contains and certain value and another column contains a different value, why does the resulting data frame that prints to the console in RStudio show several `<NA>` values in between?

I want to see the whole row in each case, so have opted for the following approach (instead of `which(geochats$origin_city == "new york" & geochats$end_city == "manassas")` which would list the row numbers of matching rows).

In this case, I would expect to see two rows printed to the console but instead I get significantly more, most of which are displaying `<NA>`.

Why does this happen?

```
> geochats[geochats$origin_city == "new york" & geochats$end_city == "manassas", ]
                                    partid       user origin_city end_city  associate
2893  2aadb2ef-c558-4902-a75b-7e5ca62b2079 WB7iSYU8yR    new york manassas CefPn1OTZF
NA                                    <NA>       <NA>        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
NA.1                                  <NA>       <NA>        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
NA.2                                  <NA>       <NA>        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
NA.3                                  <NA>       <NA>        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
NA.4                                  <NA>       <NA>        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
NA.5                                  <NA>       <NA>        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
NA.6                                  <NA>       <NA>        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
NA.7                                  <NA>       <NA>        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
NA.8                                  <NA>       <NA>        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
NA.9                                  <NA>       <NA>        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
NA.10                                 <NA>       <NA>        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
NA.11                                 <NA>       <NA>        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
NA.12                                 <NA>       <NA>        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
NA.13                                 <NA>       <NA>        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
NA.14                                 <NA>       <NA>        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
15649 e5af7b89-e38b-463f-a1ac-2e64d2e1bd24 WB7iSYU8yR    new york manassas CefPn1OTZF
NA.15                                 <NA>       <NA>        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
NA.16                                 <NA>       <NA>        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
NA.17                                 <NA>       <NA>        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
NA.18                                 <NA>       <NA>        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
```

Comment: No, `&` is correct because I want to see values where `origin_city` `AND` `end_city` equal the values that I have listed. In this case, I want to see all cases where `origin_city == "new york" AND end_city == "manassas"`.

Comment: You probably have missing values in one or both of the columns that you are checking, and subsetting a data frame with `NA` returns a row of `NA`s (try e.g. `mtcars[c(TRUE, NA), ]`). To fix this, you can e.g. wrap your condition in `which` (like you mention), to get a numeric index that doesn't include `NA` values. Or do: `subset(geochats, origin_city == "new york" & end_city == "manassas")`

Comment: As @MikkoMarttila said, just use `geochats[which(geochats$origin_city == "new york" & geochats$end_city == "manassas"), ]`

Comment: @LAP Of course, I should have thought of this.  Yes, this resolves it, thank you.  Add it as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, a logical condition does not work well for subsetting in case of missing values. Therefore, we can restrict the output of the condition by using `which()`.

```
geochats[which(geochats$origin_city == "new york" & geochats$end_city == "manassas"), ]
```

A quick example:

```
x <- c(NA, 1, 2)
```

Here, the condition `x > 1` outputs `NA FALSE  TRUE`, as it cannot be evaluated for the `NA` value. `which` now selects the position of all `TRUE` values in the output vector, and can therefore be used to subset while ignoring `NA`:

```
> x[which(x > 1)]
[1] 2
```